# MongoDB aggregation UseCase

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an usecase where i need to aggregate and group information per batchId
Order Collection has  batchId, orderStatus, createTime fields
Need a query to find the count of statuses of orders in every batch

```
{
"batchId": "1",
"pending" : "10",
"fulfilled" : "15",
"Created Date" : "04/26"      min(createTime) for the orders of that batch 
"Last Modified Date" : "04/28"   max(createTime) for the orders of that batch
},{
"batchId": "2",
"pending" : "1",
"fulfilled" : "14",
"Created Date" : "03/26"      min(createTime) for the orders of that batch 
"Last Modified Date" : "04/19"   max(createTime) for the orders of that batch 
}
```

Trying with the below query but i am unable to group / batch using this can someone suggest
but this is retrieving  results for all batches combined

```
[{
$facet: {
    inProgress: [{
            $match: {
                status: 'INPROGRESS'
            }
        },
        {
            $count: 'inProgress'
        }
    ],
    complete: [{
            $match: {
                status: 'COMPLETE'
            }
        },
        {
            $count: 'complete'
        }
    ],
    failed: [{
            $match: {
                status: 'FAILED'
            }
        },
        {
            $count: "failed"
        }
    ],
    skipped: [{
            $match: {
                status: 'SKIPPED'
            }
        },
        {
            $count: "skipped"
        }
    ],
    notstarted: [{
            $match: {
                status: 'NOTSTARTED'
            }
        },
        {
            $count: "notstarted"
        }
    ],
    triggerDate: [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "triggerDate",
            "createTime": {
                "$min": "$createTime"
            }
        }
    }],
    lastModifiedDate: [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "lastModifiedDate",
            "createTime": {
                "$max": "$createTime"
            }
        }
    }]
}},{
$project: {
    cancelled: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$inProgress.inProgress', 0]
    },
    complete: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$complete.complete', 0]
    },
    failed: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$failed.failed', 0]
    },
    failed: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$failed.failed', 0]
    },
    notstarted: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$notstarted.notstarted', 0]
    },
    triggerDate: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$triggerDate.createTime', 0]
    },
    lastModifiedDate: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$lastModifiedDate.createTime', 0]
    }
}}]
```

### Edit

To say in SQL terms i am looks at something like this

```
select
    batchId,
    (select count(status) inprogress from order a where a.batchId=outer.batchId and status IN'(INPROGRESS','NOTSTARTED') inprogress,
    (select count(status) completed from order a where a.batchId=outer.batchId and status='COMPLETED') completed
    min(createTime),
    max(createTime)
from
    order outer
group by outer.batchId
```

I did try with $group by and $push
below query gives me the count of the orders in each batch and their max
and min creation time but i need the individual status counts as well
as to how many are of these are in complete and the ones are in progress

```
db.order.aggregate([ 
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id:{ "jobId" : "$jobId"},
                triggerDate:{ $min : "$createTime"},
                lastModifiedDate:{ $max : "$createTime"},
                "count": { $sum: 1 }

            }
        }
]);
```

Comment: is this `"04/26"` real format of Created Date? add your expected result in your question.

Comment: to answer your question createTime is date 2021-04-30T00:25:30.956+00:00

Comment: please add 1) example document, 2) expected result. you can edit your question and add this details in your questions not in comment. please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) good question.

Comment: Have you tried using `$group`?

Comment: yes i have i have added it in the edit section as to what i need